# How do I get the value of a StringProperty in Python for Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

How do I get the values of a nbd.Model?  I want to return a description that is composed of several of the fields but I can't get it to work.  This is my code for my class:

```
class User(ndb.Model):
  name = ndb.StringProperty()
  email = ndb.StringProperty()

  @classmethod
  def get_description(self):
    # return "Kobe Bryant (kobe.bryant@lakers.net)"
    return self.name + ' (' + self.email + ')'
```

But name is a StringProperty object and can't be appended to a string.  How do I get the value of the StringProperty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, `self.name` accessed on an **instance** of class `User` **is** a string and can be perfectly well appended to any other string.  Your obvious mistake is in that `classmethod` decorator which makes the method apply to the **class** when it clearly must apply to a specific **instance**!