# Iterate through StringProperty

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm trying to get the value (as a string) of a StringProperty but without success.
I need to iterate through it and it raises an error if I just try and iterate through the property, since it's not an iterable.
How could I convert a StringProperty to a Python string, or to something that I can iterate through and that has a len?

EDIT:

This is how I declare the Kind that has the problem:

```
class Game(ndb.Model):
"""Game object"""
target = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
attempts_allowed = ndb.IntegerProperty(required=True)
attempts_remaining = ndb.IntegerProperty(required=True, default=5)
game_over = ndb.BooleanProperty(required=True, default=False)
user = ndb.KeyProperty(required=True, kind='User')
users_word = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
```

The last property is the one I need to iterate through. And this is the function which raises an error:

```
@classmethod
def update_users_word(self, letter):
    word_as_list = list(self.users_word)
    print ("String is: " + str(getattr(self, 'users_word')))

    for pos in self.find_letter_positions_in_word(letter, self.target):
        word_as_list[pos] = letter

    self.users_word = ''.join(word_as_list)
```

and this is the exact error:

```
Number/models.py", line 59, in update_users_word
word_as_list = list(self.users_word)
TypeError: 'StringProperty' object is not iterable
```

Hope this is more clear now

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: A StringProperty *is* a string, and you *can* iterate over it. If you are having problems, you should post the actual code and the errors.

Comment: [read for **comprehension** *specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce**.*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), since you are the only person havng this problem because it is type `str` or `unicode` it is most likely **your** code that is incorrect.

Comment: so this is an **exact duplicate** of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27751418/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-a-stringproperty-in-python-for-google-app-engine, posting the code as requested earlier would have gotten you an answer earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared this as a classmethod. That means that `self` is not an *instance* of Game, but the *class itself*. So `self.user_word` refers to the property that is defined on the class, not the string that would be available via the instance.

Use a normal `@property` decorator instead, or just leave it as a standard method.

Comment: Thanks a million times!