# How do you iterate over StringProperty as a string object?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, google-app-engine, webapp2

My code is as follows:

```
class sample(ndb.Model):
    text=ndb.StringProperty()

class sample2(webapp2.RequestHandler):
   def get(self, item):
       q = sample.query()
       q1 = query.filter(item in sample.text)
```

I want to search for a specific word(item) in the text inside sample. How do I go about it? I tried this link, but it doesn't really answer my question- [How do I get the value of a StringProperty in Python for Google App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27751418/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-a-stringproperty-in-python-for-google-app-engine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't do queries like that with the datastore (or likely any other database).  Datastore queries are based on indices, and indices are not able to store complicated information, such as whether string has a certain substring.

App Engine also has a [Search API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/search) that you can use to do more complicated text searching.

Comment: Yes you are right. I asked someone the same doubt and they said the same thing and recommended me to use documents and indexes.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, [Python 2 is deprecated](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/) since 1st of January 2020 and the Google Cloud Platform strongly encourages the [migration](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/migrate-to-python3/) to newer runtimes. Also the ndb library is no longer recommended and the code relying on it would need to be updated before you could start using the Python 3 runtime. All these reasons makes me suggest you to directly switch before you spent much time on them.

Having said that, you could find the answer in the ndb library documentation about [queries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/queries) and [properties](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/entity-property-reference). There are also a couple of examples in the [Github code samples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/6f5f3bcb81779679a24e0964a6c57c0c7deabfac/appengine/standard/ndb).

First you need to retrieve the entity with the `query()` method and then access it's data through python object property notation. More or less it will look like the following:

```
q = sample.query()            # Retrieve sample entity.
substring = 'word' in q.text  # Returns True if word is a substring of text
```